# cannot get upstart to run user job

Tags: upstart, dbus

I am trying to get upstart start a user job during the boot of my machine.

I have my conky.conf upstart config file in my $HOME/.init directory.
Wenn I run "start conky" I get this error:

```
dre@dre-laptop:~$ start conky
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.76"
(uid=1000 pid=2843 comm="start conky ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
dre@dre-laptop:~$
```

I (think I) know that this error has to do with the d-bus system (authentification). I also read (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id96) that ubuntu 12.10 already has the right configuration in the d-bus config file "/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf" to allow normal users to use upstart.

```
dre@dre-laptop:~/.init$ cat conky.conf 

description "conky, a system monitor appled"

start on lightdm
stop on shutdown

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
#expect fork

# Start conky
exec /usr/bin/conky
```

So, who knows, what do I do wrong???

greetings Andre

---

No one???
Please... give me your best shot.

Answer (score 3):

Upstart on Ubuntu currently does not enable user jobs by default. This situation will change when Ubuntu Raring is released. For the time being, you need to follow the process documented in http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#enabling and copy the `Upstart.conf` dbus configuration file from the upstream upstart project here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/view/1301/dbus/Upstart.conf