# Allow non-sudo group to control Upstart job

Tags: 12.04, server, services, upstart

I'm trying to set up an Upstart job to run on system startup, and that can also be started/stopped by members of a group other than `sudo`.  With a previous version, I used`update-rc.d` and scripts stored in `/etc/init.d/` to get this working by adding `%Group ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/scriptname` to my sudoers file, but I can't seem to get an equivalent working for Upstart.

I tried adding `%Group ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/initctl start jobname` to the sudoers file, but trying to run the command `start jobname` produces this error:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.21" (uid=1000 pid=5148 comm="start jobname " interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

As near as I can tell, that's a complaint about how my user account isn't given the power to send 'Start' messages in the D-Bus config file for Upstart.  I haven't been able to actually find any information on how to edit that file to give a group permission to access a specific service--does such an option exist?  Is there a way to edit the Sudoers file so I can run the job without editing the config file?  Am I better off just sticking with the previous version?

Answer (score 7):

You can start with finding out where the D-Bus configuration specific for Upstart is kept. See that `destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"` snippet from the error message? 
Now try to grep it in the folder with D-Bus config files:

```
vhost07:~ $ grep -r "com.ubuntu.Upstart" /etc/dbus-1
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf:    <allow own="com.ubuntu.Upstart" />
[...skipped...]
```

That `Upstart.conf` file has some examples of policies. I guess you could try to figure out the format of a policy from them. 
Then try to allow your specific user just the actions that it needs. For instance, as in:

```
<policy user="pope_benedict">
  <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
         send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
         send_member="Start"/>
</policy>
```

This should permit the `pope_benedict` user to start that job.

Note that the values for the 'allow' policy attributes are listed in your original error message.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to restart D-Bus after this! :)

Comment: I found this a bit bewildering, but this helped: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/ruby-background-processes-with-upstart-user-jobs/

Answer (score 7):

I'm personally using the following line in /etc/sudoers.d/jobname_myuser file:

```
myuser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/start jobname, /sbin/stop jobname, /sbin/restart jobname, /sbin/status jobname
```

as described here: https://serverfault.com/a/390723/68608

Answer (score 2):

Such option does not exist in sudo.

The difference between Sysv scripts and Upstart configuration files is just that: Sysv scripts are scripts, executables in their own right and you can tell sudo to allow some group to execute them. In the other hand, Upstart configuration files are merely just configuration files, not executables, so the execution of `start` (symlink to `initctl`) is the thing sudo allows. Your issue here is that allowing people to run `initctl` you allow them to `initctl` everything.

Solution is though simple if your concern in merely a single job. Make a script, say `/usr/bin/jobname.sh` with

```
#!/bin/sh
initctl $1 jobname
```

then `chmod 755 /usr/bin/jobname.sh` and finally add that executable to your sudoers file:

```
%Group ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/jobname.sh
```

This way, everyone can call `jobname.sh start` or `jobname.sh stop` to control this specific job. You might want to add some checking to allow only `start` and `stop` parameters etc.

Comment: In other words, my issue isn't that the system denies group members the ability to run `initctl`, but that Upstart refuses any signals sent by users/groups not explicitly given an Allow policy entry in Upstart.conf?  And there's no way to provide any more granularity than an all-jobs-or-none setting in the config file?

Comment: Initctl in your case is running fine even without sudoers change, Upstart is just refusing the messages from it if you don't specifically allow it for non-root users. See the other two answers. You can define dbus policy on per-job basis (see the `com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.<JOB>` part) in the Upstart.conf. Depending on your needs, it might be simpler to make this kind of script for it instead of writing dbus policies and restarting dbus etc. Dbus policy is obviously the "right" thing to do, but depending on a case, simple script might go a long way with less trouble.

Comment: Editing the DBus policy to use `com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.jobname` as the `send_interface` produced the same error message as before. If I'm right in guessing that the error output contains the signal information, it looks interface or destination don't reflect the Upstart service that the signal refers to.  I think that the service information is just arguments in the D-Bus method call message, and I'm not sure I can edit the D-Bus policy for Upstart to make decisions based on argument values.

Comment: A script of the sort you suggest is working pretty well for me, with one caveat: I've been needing to run it as `sudo jobname.sh start`, so that Upstart sees the request as coming from the `root` user.I'm making an effort to try to do this the "right" way (thus the move away from Sys-V scripts in the first place), so I'd like to get this working through a D-Bus policy or some other Upstart configuration option, but if I can't get that working I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Yes, you need to call it with `sudo`. The change in `sudoers` allows people to call the script as root to fix initctl requirements. If you implement this in production, please add checks for valid `$1`, or otherwise its huge security hole! At minimal `[ "$1" = "start" -o "$1" = "stop" ] && initctl $1 jobname` is required.

Comment: I'd also quote `"$1"`.  With your `[ "$1" = "start" -o "$1" = "stop" ]` test I believe it's safe but unquoted `$1` expansion in a script run as root is just unhealthy habit (unless word splitting is deliberately desired)...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed above dbus daemon has a configuration file that specializes it for a particular application.

```
ls /etc/dbus-1/system.d/
avahi-dbus.conf
bluetooth.conf
...
Upstart.conf
wpa_supplicant.con
```

The configuration file also establishes resource limits, security parameters, and so forth.

For details see [dbus-daemon-1(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-daemon-1)

To allow a **group** to start/stop Upstart jobs add following policy to /etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf

```
  <policy group="YourGroupName">
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
       send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
       send_type="method_call" send_member="Start" />
    <allow send_destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
       send_interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job"
       send_type="method_call" send_member="Stop" />
  </policy>
```

You should consider security implications of such policy before changing default policy. Members of the *YourGroupName* will be able to start/stop **all** Upstart jobs.

Comment: But is there a way to limit the jobs they can control?  Or is that not possible because D-Bus doesn't pay attention to message content?

Comment: I tried adding that policy to Upstart.conf (replacing the groupname with my actual groupname), restarted D-Bus, and got `start: You do not have permission to modify job: jobname` when I tried to start the service.

Comment: OK. That means that policy is successfully applied. It appears that yourjob.conf is in /etc/init. User jobs should be in ~/.init. Is it plausible in your use case to place yourjob.conf in ~/.init?

Comment: In regards of your first question: Policy defines which interfaces and members can be accessed. It does define which content/arguments can be sent/passed.

Current restrictive policy has been eased down upstream. See [cannot get upstart to run user job](http://askubuntu.com/a/222207/114487)