# How to supervise and automatically restart a process?

Tags: services

I want to have a process which will be restarted if it crashes. I googled a bit and found that an easy solution is to use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html).

I didn't understand how to configure it.

1. What is the easiest way to acomplish such a functionality?
2. How to configure it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### *This answer applies to Ubuntu versions with Upstart (<= 14.10). Use another approach for versions with Systemd (>= 15.04).*

It seems you're looking for a functionality already provided in Ubuntu with *Upstart*. The `respawn` stanza in the configuration will do exactly what you need. I would recommend against the use of a less standard way of dealing with this.

Without more details about the process you're trying to manage with it, it's hard to say what the configuration should look like. It depends on whether it forks and puts itself in the background for example. [The Upstart documentation on the `respawn` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn) should give you more information.

Unfortunately, it's not yet possible to run User Jobs properly: [cannot get upstart to run user job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219760/cannot-get-upstart-to-run-user-job)

#### Example

Let's assume we want to keep the Calculator app running, even when it's being killed with fire (signal 9).

1. Create a configuration file in `/etc/init/calculator.conf` (based on [this article](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/upstart)):

   ```
   #!upstart
   description "Calculator"

   # Start job via the daemon control script. Replace "gert" with your username.
   exec su -l gert -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/gnome-calculator'

   # Restart the process if it dies with a signal
   # or exit code not given by the 'normal exit' stanza.
   respawn

   # Give up if restart occurs 10 times in 90 seconds.
   respawn limit 10 90
   ```
2. Start it by running

   ```
   sudo start calculator
   ```
3. It opens on your current display (`:0`) and enjoy the awesomeness by seeing it restarting after closing it.

   - Identify the process ID, e.g. by doing `ps aux | grep calculator`:

     ```
     gert  13695 0.2 0.4 349744 16460 ?   Sl   13:38   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-calculator
     ```
   - Kill it with fire.

     ```
     sudo kill -9 13695
     ```
   - Watch it reappearing:

     ```
     gert  16059 4.6 0.4 349736 16448 ?   Sl   13:40   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-calculator
     ```

Note that this will be more elegant with the plans for the Ubuntu 13.04 plans with proper User Job support.

Comment: I get unknown job when i try to start it ? any ideea . i have placed the file in /etc/init

Comment: @opc0de The name of the file `servicename.conf` has to match the command to start `start servicename`. I suspect you have chosen a different name.

Comment: nope, it matches but I didn't follow your example so i think I might have an syntax error.

Comment: @opc0de Well, start by explaining more about what you're trying to accomplish in the question: what kind of application/process and how you run it for example, as well as the details about your current attempt.

Comment: Solved with your example my mistake was that i probably had a mistake into the exec statament. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15):

An extremely simple tool that can accomplish the same effect without needing configuration is `immortal`: https://immortal.run/

Simply execute the command like this:

`immortal <cmd>`

It will run in the background and restart automatically if it exits.

- `immortalctl`: View the status of running jobs. There is a `name` column which will be printed here, you can use this to refer to the job with other control commands.
- `immortalctl stop <name>`: Stops monitoring the job with the given name (it will not be automatically restarted, but the current process will continue to execute)
- `immortalctl -k <name>`: Sends SIGKILL to the current process.
- `immortalctl exit <name>`: Stops monitoring the job with the given name and removes it from the list of jobs.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for my use case in 16.04. Putting this in my bag of useful tools.

Comment: Indeed, this looks more lightweight than upstart/respawn.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to display `stdout` and `stderr` in the foreground?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, since it's usually used to run a process in the background. However, you can use `immortalctl -l out.log <cmd> && tail -f out.log` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @DavidS. you could get a combined log or have stdout and stderr  https://immortal.run/post/stderr/

Comment: Should be `immortal -l out.log <cmd> && tail -f out.log` (not `immortalctl - l ...`, thanks!

Comment: This works great on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Answer (score 1):

Startup and respawning processes are managed by "systemd" since Ubuntu 15.04, a good introduction can be found here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal

an example that get you started is available on

https://www.devdungeon.com/content/creating-systemd-service-files

This approach supersedes older ones based on /etc/inittab and upstart.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need daemon/service/background process functionality and just want to do it in the console then create a file called `autorestart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
  some_command
done
```

Then `./autorestart.sh` will automatically restart `some_command` if it exits or crashes. CTRL-C breaks the loop and quits the program cleanly.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way without "Upstart". The keyword is "inittab" :-). Although that's a file not usually altered from default, it can be used to achieve the desired respawning on SYSV machines.

Comment: I don't understand why someone REJECTED this solution. If you don't understand it, just google it; it's pointless to cut and paste here the man pages of initttab, you can read them yourself on your system! just type "man inittab"...

Comment: High quality answers detail more than "use this, figure it out on your own" :)

Answer (score 0):

ps-watcher is a tool that watches which processes are running and executes an action on defined circumstances. Let’s install it:

```
apt-get install ps-watcher
```

See the bottom of [Running HHVM with fallback to PHP-FPM](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/hhvm-with-fallback-to-php) for details - this has worked well for me.

Comment: Since it's not very long please add a summary of the code instead of the article because only a very short section applies to this question.